# How to generate buttons for random set of data

Tags: angularjs

I am developing shopping cart.
suppose we have product A with 3 variants for e.g A1,A2, and A3.
A buyer can select any variant with any number of quantity.
For e.g: He can buy A1 -10 units ,A2- 2 units, and then he proceeds with checkout.
Since both A1 & A2 are variants of A, so both of them are in single JSON called "Products".

So first of all I am listing all products, and then user selects one product , selects it's variants with quantity.
So I am fetching single selected product for e.x "A" and then showing it's variants in next page.
Now user can select quantity for each variants.

Sample :
Product A
**Varant A1 : Qunatity :+[ ]-** 
**Varant A2 : Qunatity :+[ ]-** 
**Varant A3 : Qunatity :+[ ]-** 
When user clicks on **+/-** button then only that variant should increment/decrement by 1.

I am using angular js to consume webservice.
server code is on node.js

**Controller code**

```
 $scope.getProduct = function () {
            var id = $routeParams.id;
             $http.get('/products/allProducts/'+id).then(function(res){

                $scope.product=res.data;

        });
    }
```

## Product Detail

```
<a href="/home" class=" btn-danger">[ HOME PAGE ]</a>

<div ng-init="getProduct()">

    <div class="row">
    <ul>
        <li> {{product._id}}</li>
        <li>{{product.productName}}</li>
        <li>{{product.productDescription}}</li>
        <li>{{product.merchantId}}</li>
        <li>
            <p ng-repeat="value in product.productStock">
                       <span>Sizes :<button ng-click="addMethod()" >ADD</button> {{value.size}}- {{value.color}}- {{value._id}} --count[ {{add}} ]
                       <button ng-click="subMethod()">SUB</button> </span> 
        </li>

    </ul>


   <div>total count : {{add}}</div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/home" class=" btn-danger">[ HOME PAGE ]</a>

<div ng-init="getProduct()">

<div class="row">
<ul>
    <li> {{product._id}}</li>
    <li>{{product.productName}}</li>
    <li>{{product.productDescription}}</li>
    <li>{{product.merchantId}}</li>
    <li>
        <p ng-repeat="value in product.productStock">
                   <span>Sizes :<button ng-click="addMethod(product._id, $index)" >ADD</button> {{value.size}}- {{value.color}}- {{value._id}} --count[ {{add}} ]
                   <button ng-click="subMethod()">SUB</button> </span> 
    </li>

</ul>


<div>total count : {{add}}</div>
```

Notice I just changed the parameters in addMethod function

Then in addMethod, something like this

```
$scope.addMethod = function (id_product, index){
  let product = product.findById(id);
  product.productStock[index] ++;
}
```

The id of the product is optionnal; it depends how your data is handled in your website, I assumed there were mltiple products for the same controller, so findById may be a simpel array.find method, it is up to you.

Comment: Okay, but I was thinking like, on button click, I'll save product variant id and it's count in array, and during checkout using those Id's I can process the order, what do you say. ?

Comment: Yes that's a good way to do it. :) Just create an array of object and store it like this. If the "cart" needs to be saved in multiple pages, better store it in ram and local storage too.